# In least square linear regression model, why does the test t-statistic of $\hat{\beta}$ follow a t distribution?

Tags: regression, t-distribution

In the least square linear regression model, if the explanatory variables and the error term are independent, and the error term is normal, why does the t-statistic of $\hat{\beta}$ follow a t distribution? I understand that if x is nonrandom, then the t-statistic of $\hat{\beta}$ follow a t distribution.

In other words, $\hat{\beta}$ is Gaussian conditional on X. The unconditional distribution of  $\hat{\beta}$  is non-Gaussian.

How can the test statistic still follow a t distribution?

Comment: Are you asking why, in the model $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2 I)$, we have $\hat \beta_j \sim t$? Because if so, that's not correct; $\hat \beta \sim \mathcal N(\beta, \sigma^2 (X^T X)^{-1})$. Maybe you're thinking of the test statistic?

Comment: @Chaconne I believe that OP is asking: Why do we use a test statistic that follows a t-distribution (i.e., we use the t-statistic) to test $\hat{\beta}$? Why not, for instance, something that follows a normal distribution (i.e., z-score)?

Comment: The estimate $\hat\beta$ doesn't follow a t distribution.  Are you perhaps referring to the estimate *divided by its estimated standard error*?

Answer (score 0):

The standardized $\hat{\beta}$ does have a t-distribution. While we usually are interested in that distribution conditional on the observed value of the regressor $X$, since that is what is relevant for statistical inference (see [What are the differences between stochastic and fixed regressors in linear regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215230/what-are-the-differences-between-stochastic-and-fixed-regressors-in-linear-regre/417324#417324)  and  [What is the difference between conditioning on regressors vs. treating them as fixed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144826/what-is-the-difference-between-conditioning-on-regressors-vs-treating-them-as-f/192746#192746)).

But, since this conditional distribution of the test statistic ($\hat{\beta}$ divided by its standard error) **does not depend on $X$**, the unconditional distribution is in fact the same.