# Confused with the fundamental assumptions of Frequentist and Bayesian Linear Regression

Tags: regression, probability, bayesian, least-squares, posterior

In Frequentist Linear Regression, I have seen 2 approaches which lead to basically similar models. We have $W,y,X,\epsilon$ related as $y=W^TX+\epsilon$, where $y$ is the dependent **random** variable, and $X$ is assumed to be a constant (**first approach**), or random (**second**) independent variable. $\epsilon$ is assumed to be the Gaussian error. Now let us say we assume $X$ as a random variable, of which, we don't know the probability distribution. (At least the sources I've read don't talk about its distribution) 
We also write the the data as $\{(x_i,y_i)_n\}$, and this notation is widely used:
$$p(D)=p(y|X)\tag{i}$$
where "$D$" is often called the Data. (**(1)Is it a random variable?**)
Well then, we get (assuming parameters of $\epsilon$ to be constant),
$$p(y|W,X)=N(W^TX,\sigma_\epsilon^2)$$ and compute the MLE. 
Now coming to the semi Bayesian, we know a prior distribution of $W$. Now we wish to know the posterior, given the data D. That is, $$p(W|D)=_{\text{Def of Conditional Probability}} \frac{p(W,D)}{p(D)}=\frac{p(D|W)p(W)}{p(y|X)}$$
**(2)Now, how do we compute $p(D|W)$? (All we are given is $(i)$, about $p(D)$)**

Now coming to the pure Bayesian, we basically want $$p(y|X,D) =\frac{p(y,X,D)}{p(x,D)}$$
I was told at school that this equals $$\int_Wp(y|W,X)p(W|D)dW$$ **(3)How to arrive at this?** 
Please use only basic stuff like definitions to derive this. I have found so many interpretations and ways of these, that I literally have no idea what is the correct way to look at it. So please provide answers to the questions in bold. 
**Also, if there is any mistake in the above reasoning, please point out.**

Comment: In (i) if D is (x,y) then $p(D)=p(x,y) \neq p(x|y)$

Comment: @user0, okay, but I still don't see how it solves the other issues. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Is $D=\{(X_i,y_i)_n\}$ a random variable?

Yes, since $y_i$ are random variables. Are $X_i$ random variables? Theoretically yes, but is not always useful to consider them as such. Since the regression weights $W$ only affect the distribution of $y_i|X_i$, we can say:

$$p(W|D)=p(W|X,y)=\frac{p(W,x,y)}{\int\int p(W,x,y)dxdy}=\frac{p(W)p(X)p(y|X,w)}{\int p(W')p(X)p(y|X,W')dW'}=\frac{p(W)p(y|X,w)}{\int p(W')p(y|X,W')dW'}$$

Since $p(X)$ cancels in the calculation of the posterior $p(W|D)$, we can safely ignore the distribution of $X$ and consider it fixed instead of random.

There are, of course, some exceptions: when $X$ includes some missing data, considering $X$ as random allows us to manage imputation in a quite principled way: we just marginalize the missing values out when finding the posterior. But in the absence of missing values, I do not see any advantages to considering $X$ as random with some distribution $p(X)$.

Also, note that $p(D)=p(y|X)$ when $X$ is fixed. When $X$ is considered random, $p(D)=p(y,X)=p(y|X)p(X)$.

### How do I calculate $p(D|W)$?

Since you assume a normal model, where $p(y|X,W)$ is normal, you have simply:
$$p(D|W)=\prod_{i=1}^n p(X_i,y_i|W)=\prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i|X_i,W)p(x_i)$$

If you take $x$ as fixed, you can safely ignore $p(X)$ in the above equation.

### How to arrive at $p(y^\star|X^\star,D)=\int p(y^\star|W,X^\star)p(W|D)dW$?

This equation refers to the posterior predictive distribution: after we fit our model on data $D$, how do I predict the value $y^\star$ given the covariate vector $X^\star$? (I added $\star$ here to emphasize that $X^\star$ and $y^\star$ refer to new observations not included in the original data $D$).

Then, the equation you wrote follow by applying the **law of total probability**. In details, we have:

$$p(y^\star|X^\star,D)=p(y^\star|X^\star,D)\cdot\int p(W|D)dW \\= \int p(y^\star|X^\star,D)\cdot p(W|D)dW=\int p(y^\star,W|X^\star,D)dW\\=\int p(y^\star|W, X^\star)p(W|D)dW$$

You might find these questions about the law of total probability useful:

- [Can we prove the law of total probability for continuous distributions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035418/can-we-prove-the-law-of-total-probability-for-continuous-distributions)
- [How to think about Continuous Total Probability Theorem applied to a conditional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3148634/how-to-think-about-continuous-total-probability-theorem-applied-to-a-conditional)

Hope it was helpful!

Comment: Amazing. Just an observation, there's no need to "assume" that $X$ is fixed in the second part. The $p(X_i)$ term just cancels out from the denominator!

Comment: Great answer :). Just a question. In the third right-hand side term of the expression that defines $p(W|D)$, would it be correct to consider in the numerator $p(W|X)p(X)$ instead of $p(W)p(X)$?

Comment: @JavierTG Good point! It would indeed be correct to consider p(W|X)p(X). When I write it as p(W)p(X), I am assuming than W and X are independent. It makes sense: if I didn't know the values of Y and someone told me the values of the the covariates X, I wouldn't learn anything about W.

Comment: See also (frequentist ...) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144826/what-is-the-difference-between-conditioning-on-regressors-vs-treating-them-as-f/192746#192746   and   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215230/what-are-the-differences-between-stochastic-v-s-fixed-regressors-in-linear-regr/417324#417324