# Does maximum likelihood need to account for the probability of input covariates?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

I am reading "Probabilistic Machine Learning" by K. Murphy. In it, he defines the likelihood of a dataset as

[image]

However, this dataset $D$ is defined as:

[image]

So if all $x_n, y_n$ are random variables, it would seem that one needs to account for $p(x_n|\theta)$ via conditional probability? I assume this would factor out if assumed to be a constant, but I didn't see this explicitly stated.

Please excuse this potentially naive question.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144826/what-is-the-difference-between-conditioning-on-regressors-vs-treating-them-as-f/192746#192746  and   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215230/what-are-the-differences-between-stochastic-and-fixed-regressors-in-linear-regre/417324#417324