Does the factorization theorem prove that the simplest factorization of the PDF is the most informative?
Let me state the factorization theorem as: the existence of a PDF factorization where $X$ depends on the parameter only through $T(X)$, proves $T(X)$ is sufficient, defined as conveying the maximum possible parameter information from $X$. Its proof (or all versions I've found) shows how one can factor a PDF into the simple product of two components, one independent of the parameter and the other depending on the parameter only through $T(X)$.
This is just algebra, proving only the statement: "Some PDFs can be factored in this way." The proof then imposes, definitionally, that $T(X)$ is sufficient. It seems to rely on an intuitively appealing, but mathematically unjustified, assumption: the information of a PDF's individual factors cannot exceed their collective information. This assumption fails to consider, much less to exclude, another possibility: there may exist a partition of the simplest factorization into many factors, some or all of which individually increase the information of $T(X)$ conditionally, but which collectively cancel. Let me illustrate.
Basu (1964) showed for bivariate normal sample $(X, Y)$ with population correlation $\rho$, $X$ and $Y$ are separately ancillary but jointly sufficient (though obviously not minimal sufficient). In this particular case, conditional inference is not possible, i.e., neither $r\mid X$ nor $r\mid Y$ is more informative than sufficient statistic Pearson's $r$. But can we prove no such example exists? Shouldn't we have to for the FT to hold?
The upshot is, it's basic algebra to pull factors out of polynomials that otherwise cancel$-$say, the product of a factor and its reciprocal, or equal addends of opposite sign. Shouldn't the FT have to refute this possibility? If it doesn't, isn't it just an axiom? Or is there a flaw in my logic? Keep in mind my example is illustrative only: the burden isn't on me to prove a counterexample, but on the FT to prove there can be no counterexample.

The factorization theorem does not prove anything about the PDF. It just defines the sufficient statistic as any factor of the PDF that includes the parameter. One deduces from this that the sample depends on the parameter only through the sufficient statistic. The deduction is what technically makes it a theorem, but most "proofs" just show how one would apply the factorization theorem, and it is sometimes just called the factorization "criterion."
That the sufficient statistic conveys all inferentially-useful information (i.e., the evidence produced by the experiment, as Birnbaum put it in his classic paper on the Strong Likelihood Principle) is a separate assumption, called the Sufficiency Principle (SP). The SP is not a theorem but an axiom, one that implicitly depends on another axiom, called the Distribution Principle (DP). The DP just says that one loses no evidence by reducing the sample to a sufficient statistic.
There is a long list of counterexamples to the DP. The example of Basu, cited in the question, is one. Contrary to a statement in the question, the example is not trivial: Kabaila and Welsh (2024) show (or claim to show, through unreported Monte Carlo simulations) that the confidence interval for Pearson's $r$ is at least as narrow and can be narrower, when either $X$ or $Y$ is held fixed and conditioned upon. (See that source for citations to other examples in the literature.) Berger proves an equivalent (if somewhat contrived) counterexample to the DP as a discussant in Barnard (1983).
More generally, the DP does not hold in all cases when the statistic is conditioned upon an ancillary statistic; K&W prove this will often be the case when the ancillary is not a function of the minimal sufficient statistic. Counterexamples are sometimes referred to as "ancillarity paradoxes" (although the term applies more broadly to cases where estimators are admissible conditionally but not unconditionally). They suggest, in fact, that "conditional frequentist inference" ought to be treated as a separate paradigm from frequentist inference.
Fraser and Reid (1990), on the other hand, take a more practical stance. They view the SP as just one of many classical optimality criteria, and they argue conditional inference ought to be the rule. Mindless adherence to optimality criteria is naive, they say, because the scientific method is inherently conditional--and messy. Or, more succinctly: "I do not think anyone regards it as paradoxical that an approximation that works well in one situation works poorly in another” (Hill, 1990, p. 520).
So they'd probably resolve Basu's "paradox," for example, by pointing out that a) the correlation, when applied with one factor fixed, is a different measure, despite having the same formula and PDF (and likelihood function); and b) whether one conditions on fixed $X$ (or fixed $Y$) ought to be determined by the research question and the experimental context. Ask: Does this factor vary at random? Do I want to make a generalizable inference? The conditional statistic may provide greater information (smaller variance), but it cannot provide greater evidence, if it answers a different question.
Interestingly, while Basu's (1964) example violates the SP (by conditionally defining a correlation measure more informative than the sufficient statistic), it arguably does not violate the factorization theorem. Under bivariate normality, the sufficient statistic is Pearson's $r$. One could say the joint statistic $(r, X)$, for fixed $X$, is a "supersufficient" statistic (in homage to the superefficiency). But then, so is $(r, Y)$, for fixed $Y$. If we then gave the sufficient statistic as $(r, X, Y)$, however, $X$ and $Y$ would drop out as redundant: the sample $(X, Y)$ is obviously a sufficient statistic, so its parameter information equals that of $r$. Thus, the sample depends upon the parameter only through $r$.

Excerpt from my working paper on an adjacent topic, which inspired the question.

The definition of sufficiency doesn't involve information. A statistic $T(X)$ is sufficient for a parameter $\theta$ if the conditional distribution $X\mid T(X)$ does not depend on $\theta$.
The factorisation theorem gives a condition for $T$ to be sufficient. This  is very straightforward for discrete or sufficiently smooth continuous cases, and almost looks trivial, but is quite subtle for more general cases.
Neither the definition nor the factorisation theorem directly addresses the question of whether there might be another way to extract more information.  That's a further result or results, and depends on exactly what you mean by information. In that direction we have:

the Cram'er-Rao variance bound for an estimator computed from $T(X)$ is the same as for an estimator computed from $X$
the Rao-Blackwell theorem says that conditioning on a sufficient statistic improves any estimator
the Lehman-Scheff'e theorem says that all the estimators that attain the Cram'er-Rao variance bound are functions of a minimal sufficient statistics
likelihood ratios based on $X$ and on $T(X)$ are the same, so the most powerful test for any point null and alternative is the same
likelihood ratios based on $X$ and on $T(X)$ are the same, so the asymptotic efficiency bound in the Convolution Theorem and Local Asymptotic Minimax theorem are the same for both.
likelihood ratios based on $X$ and on $T(X)$ are the same, so posterior beliefs about $\theta$ based on observing $T(X)$ are/should be the same as based on $X$


To be clear, when Wikipedia says "A sufficient statistic contains all of the information that the dataset provides about the model parameters," this is false? Not to say that Wikipedia is the ultimate source for statistics, but the same language appears in many stats texts, and articles going back to Fisher's seminal papers on sufficiency. Has there been a re-evaluation of the implications of sufficiency since his day, which somehow has not penetrated standard sources? If so, you'd think this would be a controversial topic on the Wikipedia talk page and elsewhere...

Wikipedia is a bit imprecise in this case.  "All of the information" is the motivation for the concept of sufficiency, but it is not part of the definition or of the factorisation theorem.  If "all of the information" were straightforwardly untrue, however, sufficiency wouldn't have been an interesting concept (or it would be defined differently). It has also been re-evaluated a bit since Fisher because so few problems have finite-dimensional sufficient statistics.

My problem is, I can't tell if your interpretation is the consensus view among the broader statistics community, or if it's the view within a particular statistical school. By analogy, Bayesians have mathematical formulations of probability as prior belief; likelihoodists have their counterexamples to Mayo's disproof of the SLP; etc. Maybe mathematical statisticians have re-evaluated, while those in other subfields continue to define the FT as I did above. Can you cite some general authority to the effect that "all the information" is the motivation and not the implication of sufficiency?

Although, possibly the problem is resolved by distinguishing between sufficiency and the Sufficiency Principle. According to the top answer at stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379798/: "The Sufficiency Principle says that we should draw the same conclusions in two experiments where a sufficient statistic has the same value." Then perhaps the factorization theorem and/or the definition of sufficiency as conditional independence of the sample from the parameter, plus the SP, together imply Wikipedia's definition of sufficiency. Mathematical statistics does not encompass all of estimation theory

+1.  Mathematical results like these are not a matter of contention, philosophy, consensus, or style among the statistics community: they are the basic, proven facts on which we rely for justification.

@whuber We should be skeptical when it comes to proofs involving continuous mathematics as the universe is likely to be discrete. Some examples where math fails us or gets us into philosophical discussions are No Free Lunch Theorem, Differential Entropy, Distributions With Infinite Support. I don’t know yet any machinery invented that can generate data points with infinite precision or from an infinite support.

@Cagdas I appreciate those points, but it's important to distinguish the mathematical theories and results from how they are applied.  Your thoughts address only the latter: there's no disputing the correctness of "continuous mathematics."

@virtuolie there's literally no dispute about the definition of sufficiency. The sufficiency principle is exactly what you are disputing: it's the principle that a sufficient statistic contains all the evidence -- and as I said, that's a separate idea. There are theorems (such as the ones I referred to) that make the sufficiency principle seem plausible. I don't think the sufficiency principle is all that controversial -- not like the conditionality principle or the likelihood principle.

@ThomasLumley: I think you mistook my 2 comments as disagreement, which wasn't intended. My 1st comment just asked for a scholarly source that it's a consensus view, that "sufficiency = all the information" motivates, but is not implied by, sufficiency. It's easy to find sources (like wikipedia) defining sufficiency as "all the information," as if it's equivalent to the factorization definition--likely the source of my post's error. A concrete citation would help combat the misconception. My 2nd comment was my "ah-ha!" moment, realizing I'd wrongly attributed to the FT a consequence of SP...

(continued) In sum, your answer above does answer my question, but it doesn't quite explain it as well as your comments do. It's true the theorems aren't about information, but it really helped to have you explicitly make the distinction between estimation theorems and estimation principles, as they constitute estimation theory. I studied stats originally as QM, where this is not emphasized enough. I'd still like a source if you have it. I'd rather be able to cite something than say "Lumley told me this on StackExchange" or recap the argument as a folk theorem.

@whuber: This is not a disagreement with, but an extension of, your comment. Mathematics, even pure math, is a human endeavor, where theorems become incorporated into the discipline not by being correct but by consensus. This is important--not just philosophizing!--because it means we can cite a proof instead of rearguing it every time. But also because all theorems rely implicitly on the fabric of the paradigm. If paradigms are models and all models are wrong, then all theorems are wrong, in the sense of Lakatos (Proofs and Refutations). Some who question "proven facts" are not fools.
