Why variance of least square estimator in simple regression is conditional on predictor?
I'm a new to statisics and now reading the book Applied Linear Regression by Sanford Weisberg. I may be asking a non-sensical question, but why does variance of least square estimator $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ in simple regression are $Var(\hat{\beta_0} |X)$ and $Var(\hat{\beta_1} |X)$ instead of $Var(\hat{\beta_0})$ and $Var(\hat{\beta_0})$?
Suppose we have random variables $X$ and $Y$; and we have realization $x_i$ and $y_i$. I estimated these parameters $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ using the sample predictor $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ and response $\mathbf{y} = (y_1,y_2,...y_n)$. So I think the variability of $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ should come from sampling from $X$ plus random error of $Y$ conditional on $X$. However, using $Var(\hat{\beta_0} |X)$ and $Var(\hat{\beta_1} |X)$ suggests that variability only come from random error of $Y$.
The same question comes to the proof of unbiasedness of estimators $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$. The book proves that $E(\hat{\beta_0}|X)=\beta_0$ and $E(\hat{\beta_1}|X)=\beta_1$ but I think the aim should be $E(\hat{\beta_0})$ and $E(\hat{\beta_1})$.

Hi: There are two different version of OLS: OLS with fixed regressors and OLS with random regressors. It may be that Weisberg is considering the case of random regressors so he conditions on X. Do you have Kennedy's "econometrics". His book is unique and I always recommend it to people who are trying to under the OLS assumptions. He devotes a chapter to each assumption.

This doesn't answer your question, but for context: I have never seen a use-case of linear regression where the predictors $X$ are treated as random variables. Usually they are treated as known, so the only source of variance comes from the error in $Y$.

Hi Alex J: How to understand "predictors X are treated as known" if it is not prespecified?  For example, we want to know how does age (X) influence bloodpressure (Y) so we collect data of a sample from a population; I think both age and bloodpressure are here random variables.

Hi mlofton: I think this case is for random regressors. My problem is that why the estimators are conditioned on X. I could understand Y is condtioned on X because that's exact problem we are looking for. But I cannot grasp the point why our estimators are conditioned on X.

Hi chenpunk: I'm not experienced with random regressor case but, as far as the estimators being conditioned on $X$, all that is saying is that they depend on $X$. Consider $\hat{\beta_{1}} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} y_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}x_{i}}$. So, since the estimate is a function of $X$, it depends on $X$. Is that what you are asking ?

chenpunk: hopefully others can say more but the name of the book I mentioned is actually "A Guide To Econometrics".  It's fairly technical but the technical details are not the focus of the book. He has a really unique way of explaining things. Unfortunately, he passed away probably 10 years ago.

@chenpunk imo, it depends on the context. So say we are studying how does age (X) influence bloodpressure (Y). It is of course true that when we pick a person from the population, we will draw from a distribution of ages. But to answer the question of interest in this example, the distribution of X is actually not relevant.

Good and important question, which has been treated in earlier posts on this site. Regression models are conditional models, they answer questions such as "knowing $x$, can we use it to predict $Y$? If so, how good?". That indicates that even if $x$ is random, once we have the realized value, only that is relevant for the uncertainty in the regression coefficient. Therefore the interest in $Var(\hat{\beta_0} |X)$ and $Var(\hat{\beta_1} |X)$.
If $\beta=(\beta_0, \beta_1)$ is the true regression coefficient, then typically the distribution of $x$ itself does not contain information about $\beta$. We say the distribution of $x$ is ancillary. But, in many examples ancillary statistics contain information about the precision of an estimator, even if it does not contain information about the parameter itself. A very simple example is estimation of a mean. Say $X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_N$ is a random sample from some distribution with mean $\mu$, and we want to estimate $\mu$. But here $N$ itself is random, we decided on $n$ by throwing a coin. If heads we decided $N=10$, if tails we decided $N=20$.
Since the throw of this dice in itself does not tell us anything about $\mu$, it is ancillary. The randomness of $N$ should not play any role in calculating a standard error of $\bar{x}$, we should use 10 or 20, not their mean ...
This seems quite clear in this example, and then think about that $x$ in the regression case plays the same role as $N$ in this simple analogy.
A more formal answer can be found at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/192746/11887

Thank you! The conception of ancillary statistics and two steps to construct joint the distribution of  $X$ and $Y$ helps me on understanding the underlying logic. :)

This is a good question, but it requires a very delicate and careful answer. I hope I don't scuff it up.

First, there is a matter of how we model the generation of our datasets. Depending on the exact details of our experiments, we might encounter situations in which $X$ is fixed and other situations in which $X$ is random.

fixed $X$: if $X$ is chosen by the experimenter ahead of time. For example, a latin square design (here is some material on the topic but I couldn't find something with a higher-level view); or perhaps a physical experiment in which we choose ahead of time that we will sample $X$ in a grid over possible parameter values
random $X$: if $X$ is a measured quantity on a sample of a larger population. This is the most typical case.


Second, there is the question of what we want to learn from our data. If a question has been framed as a regression problem / supervised learning problem, it typically means that $X$ is easy to measure while $Y$ is harder to measure. This means that it is meaningful to try to learn the relationship between the two in order to find an easily-measurable surrogate of $Y$


The emphasis on conditional modelling stems from that second point. Regardless of whether $X$ is random or fixed, we aim to learn something about the conditional $X|Y$. Given that $X$ is easy to measure, it makes sense to condition on its value in the resulting analysis.
I hope that makes things clearer. Please don't hesitate if you have further questions.
Two additional remarks:

It's important to note that proving properties conditional on $X$ can easily be extended to random $X$ by marginalization. For example, the linear regression is unbiased $E(\hat \beta_0) = \beta_0$ since it is unbiased for all realizations of $X$.

Another very subtle point is that the analysis of linear regression stands slightly in tension with a basic view of frequentist statistics. Here, the property of the estimator are conditional on part of the dataset. The same is also true for bootstrap methods which resample the original data.



Thank you very much. So can I regard the estimated $\hat{\beta}$ as $\hat{\beta}|X$? I posted this question because I noticed $\sqrt{Var(\hat{\beta}|X)}$ is not the standard error of estimator like that of other models. It is irrelevant to sampling process. Moreover, I'm still a little confused. How do we interpret the property of estimator conditioned on part of dataset here? Or more precisely, what does variance of estimated $\hat{\beta}|X$ mean?
