# Estimate AR(1) using Log returns

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

I am studying share price log returns and AR(1) model.

I downloaded data from FTSE100 and used the Adj.close column to find the Ln returns:

[image]

[image]

Now I am trying to understand how can I estimate an AR(1) model using this information. I understand the AR(1) model, I did a couple of example in excel, but I do not understand how the ln returns are related to that. 
AR(1) is given by:

$X_t=\phi+\alpha*X_{t-1}+\epsilon$

I assume that I need to find values for $\phi$ and $\alpha$ to try to fit the AR(1) model but I am confused.
Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is unclear for you?

Comment: How to estimate an AR(1) model with this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing this in Excel, the simplest way would be to use linear regression (but [not the best](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52458/inclusion-of-lagged-dependent-variable-in-regression)). Notice that if your model is

$$
Y_t = \phi + \alpha Y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t
$$

that it is basically the same as standard linear regression model

$$
Y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_t + \varepsilon_t
$$

with $X_t = Y_{t-1}$.

Assuming that your $Y_t$ variable is stored in the `A1:A100` cells, put lagged $Y_{t-1}$ in `B2:B100` cells, by inserting there `=A1:A99`. Then you can extimate $\alpha$ `=SLOPE(A2:A99, B2:B99)` and $\phi$ `=INTERCEPT(A2:A99, B2:B99)`.

Comment: Makes sense, so the values of $X_t$ are the returns for each t right?

Comment: The A column in the example is $Y_t$ and B column is $Y_{t-1}$, if $Y$ is returns, then $Y_{t-1}$ are lagged returns.