# Should I use a difference-in-difference method for migration flows and average unskilled worker incomes or a lagged DV?

Tags: regression, time-series, stata, difference-in-difference, lags

I am using data from a variety of sources to measure if migration inflows lead to an increase in unskilled worker wages. I am controlling for number of illegal immigrants, migrant unemployment, etc. 
I think that I will see results that show that an increase in migration will lead to an increase in average unskilled worker wages in relation to the median income because I think they will be filling gaps in the work force. 
Anyway, would I want to lag my dependent variable in this analysis? Or use the difference-in-difference statistical test?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your rationale for potentially using a lagged DV?  And what kind of diff-in-diff would it be?  What would be the intervention (i.e., pre- and post- periods) and treatment and control groups?  And why are you limiting yourself to these two methods?

Comment: There is already a question concerning using lagged dependent variable in regression, with answers that talk about the pros and cons of this method: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/52458/241093